# VS Code is not listing all my Azure Subscriptions

Tags: azure, vscode-extensions, azure-subscription

I have an Azure subscription, in fact, there are two of them. In one I am the owner and I have created it, in the other I am an admin because I got it through Microsoft Sponsorship.

Now I want to work with resources under each of the subscriptions using my VS Code to view files for my services such as the uploaded code files in particular Azure App Service. I have added the Azure Extension and `*Azure Subscription *1` works fine, but `*Microsoft Azure Sponsorship*` doesn't show on the side panel.

What could be the issue?

I tried logging in with my GitHub Account on VS Code, I tried signing out of my Azure Account and back in again.

Comment: Are both subscriptions related to same Account?

Comment: Have you selected all subscriptions (Open Command Palette with Ctrl + Shift + P and open "Azure: Select Subscription") in the filter?

Comment: @PravallikaKV Both these subscriptions are listed under my account on my Azure Portal, one was created by myself and for the other I redeemed credits (It's sponsored).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the issues, thanks to @bursson, it turns out I just needed to have all the subscriptions selected on the command palette.

`Ctrl + Shift + P` then search subscriptions click on `Azure: Select Subscriptions`

You will then see checkboxes and select all the subscriptions you want, from there click OK. You'll be sorted ✅ .